# how to find confusion matrix and the accuracy rate from precision and recall values?

Tags: machine-learning, confusion-matrix, evaluate, precision-recall

I get an average of precision 82.59 and recall 69.84 using [bboxPrecisionRecall](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/bboxprecisionrecall.html) for [segmenting Arabic words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935911/why-i-get-0s-as-output-when-i-tried-to-calculate-accuracy-for-image-segmented-re) algorithm. I need to calculate TN, FP, FN, and TP using the [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) to evaluate the performance of the model.
Is the precision same as the accuracy? If not, how can I calculate it?
The segmentation method applied to 1131 images and compared with ground truth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too sure about how the confusion matrix is arranged in MATLAB, but in Python, the one imported from sklearn.metrics is arranged as such:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

confusion_matrix(ground_truth, predictions) = array([[TN, FP],
                                                      FN, TP]])
```

Accuracy is not the same as precision. Precision is measured using TP/(TP+FP) while accuracy is measured using (TP+TN)/(TP+TN+FP+FN)

Comment: Could I get one value by using these equations?

Comment: Precision = 82.59 and recall = 69.84 and recall = TP/(TP+FN)

Comment: Total = TP+FP+TN+FN ,  the value of Total = 1131

Comment: What do you mean by one value?

Comment: The confusion matrix is needed 4 values known, isn't it? I have got one value for recall. If I can calculate to get one more value I could get the two values.

Comment: I see what you mean. If you could also obtain the accuracy score, then it'd be possible to calculate the individual values of TP, TN, FP and FN since you will need at least 4 different eqn to calculate 4 unknowns.

Comment: Is there another way to calculate one of them, and then get the three others by eqn?